# USB headset only works the first time I plug it in on Macbook Pro

Tags: audio, usb, headphones

I have a bit of an annoying problem with my Macbook Pro  (16", 2019 model) running Big Sur (11.4).

I have a Logitech USB headset. Since my laptop only has USB-C ports, I have a plug to convert between the two USB formats.

The first time I plug in my headset after a reboot, it works as expected. However, if I unplug the USB plug what happens afterwards is unpredictable. But in all cases when I plug in the same headset in a different USB-C port, the light on the cable will blink after a second or so and nothing happens. In some cases if I plug in the USB in the same port as the previous time, it works as expected.

So this means that every time I unplug my head set, I basically need to reboot my machine to be sure it will work the next time I plug it in. This is a bit cumbersome.

I have tried going through the system logs but I couldn't find anything related to this. Is there anything I could do, even if just a command I could use to restart only the USB subsystem. Basically anything that fixes or circumvents this issue?

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: No I have not found anything yet. Still thanks for the moral support :)